# jQuery loading HTML

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load HTML in to an area on my page and I can load pure text all okay, see example below:

```
function(msg) {
    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
    $("#CategoryExtension").text(msg);
}
```

However when I try to include HTML content it displays it as is, and places a quote around the content.

How can I get over this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*HTML* ? Try

```
$("#CategoryExtension").html(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

remember that, there is **text()** and **html()**

**text()** is the same as the Text property and **html()** is the innerHTML property, when playing with div's you should change the innerHTML property just like

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = 'This is <strong>my bold text</strong>.';
```

in the jQuery world you accomplish the same as

```
$("#myDiv").html('This is <strong>my bold text</strong>.');
```

it helps understand a little bit about HTML and Javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `html( )`. For example:

```
$("#CategoryExtension").html("<span>Hello</span>");
```

Also, please check out [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) to familiarize yourself with the API. It will help you a lot.